# How to fix this Flipped Pose Rotation?

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

UPDATE : Problem Solved when change the bone axis from X to -X

Look at the hand rotation, whrn i copy paste flipped from the left hand to the right hand, it doesn't mirror the rotation, i'm so confused, this is my first time having this problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, we need to at least see two more screen shots, showing the axis of the bones and the weight painting of that arm.  Better would be if you could include your blend file in your question (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Did you use CTRL V or CTRL SHIFT V to paste the pose? Either way, as @Marty Fouts says we'll need more information.

Comment: @MartyFouts Ok, i already give the file

Comment: the problem is only happen to the hands (wrist and fingers)

Comment: @JohnEason CTRL SHIFT V